# Finding origin of a host address

Tags: windows, hostname

I have a Windows server which is resolving a name. I do not know from where the address comes from: it should not be on DNS, and it is not on `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

When I try looking the name up with `nslookup` it tells me that the name does not exist. However the `ping` tool is able to look the name up.

How can I find from where does the resolution come from?

Comment: Open command prompt, and do "nslookup servername" and it will tell you what DNS server you are using, and that DNS server is what make the server name resolves to an IP address. You don't happen to be using OpenDNS do you?

Comment: nslookup says that it does not exist, and hosts file does not have it. Where can the IP address come from?

Comment: Also if you set the nslookup to `set query=ptr` it'll show you the primary name server information as well.

Comment: I repeat that name can not be found by nslookup and is not available in hosts. But ping still resolves it.

Comment: Flush your DNS.

Comment: What is the name you are seeing?

Comment: IIRC looking up the IP address is a 5-step process, involving caches as well. I do not remember the eact number and sequence, but I have that information from one of the earlier episodes of Security Now. The transcribed texts are searchable at https://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm

Comment: run `ipconfig /flush-dns` as per shinjijai's recommendation, if it still resolves the name afterwards.. I'd start thinking about malware.

Comment: Have you checked your lmhosts file as well?

Comment: lmhosts is empty. ipconfig /flush-dns and it is still resolved by ping, but still not by nslookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a FQDN, and NSLookup can't find it but ping can, then it's probably a NetBIOS name being broadcasted by the remote machine and not a DNS entry, HOSTS entry, or anything on the local system, or anything handled by a central server (assuming you don't have a WINS server set up).

You can use `nbtstat -r` to get a list of host names that were resolved via NetBIOS (over TCP/IP) broadcasts.

> Host name resolution generally uses the following sequence:
>
> 1. The client checks to see if the name queried is its own.
> 2. The client then searches a local Hosts file, a list of IP address and names stored on the local computer.
> 3. Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried.
> 4. If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution sequence is used as a backup. This order can be changed by configuring
>      the NetBIOS node type of the client.

Above quote from MS KB172218: [Microsoft TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172218)